# Interactive Infowindow Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This probably has a very simple answer, but I just couldn't get it to work.

First Part (not working). Inside infowindow:

```
    dataTitle = place.name;
    content += "<input type='button' value='Add this Spot' onclick='addToList("+place.geometry.location.lat()+","+place.geometry.location.lng()+",dataTitle);' >";
```

Alert dataTitle on the spot works fine, however dataTitle is empty in the addToList function for some reason.

Second Part (Working). Now I use the exact same thing OUTSIDE of customed infowindow and it works just fine...

```
    dataTitle = $(this.content).find("div.gm-title").text();
    var link = $("<input type='button' value='Add this Spot' onclick='latLngSet(dataTitle)' >");

function latLngSet(title) {
    addToList(userLatitude,userLongitude,title);
}
```

Latitude and Longitude both display correctly, just the title is showing blank inside custom infowindow...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting datatitle in the link string like text not a value. Try this:

```
dataTitle = $(this.content).find("div.gm-title").text();
var link = $("<input type='button' value='Add this Spot' onclick='latLngSet("+ dataTitle +")' >");

function latLngSet(title) {
    addToList(userLatitude,userLongitude,title); }
```

Comment: The second part works fine, but not the first part. First part shows empty when doing addToList function call.
Second part actually calls out the title... even though they are like the same thing..

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so I can see what you're doing? I'm not sure I understand you. So the function latLngSet works but not if you call it by the input button?